# Position image wont overlap two continers

Tags: html, css

Hi I am trying to create a personal website and am having some problems with the styling at my header, specificaly related to positioning.This is how my header looks now:

[image]

The NA in the middles is actually an image circle that should overlap the black borders , but I can not seem to figure out how to do it.This is my markup:

```
 <section class="top-bottom-border overflow">
    <div class="center">
        <ul id="social">
            <li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/nistor.alexandru.89" target="_blank"><img src="images/social/FacebookIco.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="https://twitter.com/aleczandru89" target="_blank"><img src="images/social/TwitterIco.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=225866296&trk=tab_pro" target="_blank"><img src="images/social/LinkedinIco.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/profile/view?id=225866296&trk=tab_pro" target="_blank"><img src="images/social/LinkedinIco.png"></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
<nav class="center overflow" id="menu">
    <ul class="float-left">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul id="logo">
        <li><a href="#" title="About me"><img src="images/Logo.png" alt="logo"/></a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="float-right">
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact me</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
<section class="top-bottom-border"></section>
```

And this is my css:

```
   .center {
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 960px;
    }
.overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
        .top-bottom-border {
        background: url(../images/top-bottom-border.jpg);
        height: 37px;
    }
    ul#social{
        float: right;
    }
    ul#social li {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
    nav#menu{
        position: relative;
        height: 50px;
    }
    nav#menu li{
        display: inline-block;
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 20px;
    }
    nav#menu .float-left{
        padding-left: 150px;
    }
    nav#menu .float-left li{
        margin-right: 25px;
    }
    nav#menu .float-right{
        padding-right: 150px;
    }
    nav#menu .float-right li{
        margin-left: 25px;
    }
    ul#logo{
        position: absolute;
        left: 400px;
        top:-40px;
    }
```

How can I make the image in the center overlap the two black borders?

Comment: hey, can you post it on **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)** with the links for the images as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<nav class="center overflow" id="menu">` the `z-index` isn't coming into act because you've `overflow: hidden` for your `#nav` so the logo that overflows it is not displayed. Removing *overflow* class from it will fix display of your logo.

**Edit** As far as I can understand your layout and the goal, you might also want to add `float: left` to `nav#menu .float-left` and `float :right` to `nav#menu .float-right`

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a style="z-index: 5" to the li or ul of the logo

Comment: already tryed that won't work since I am not adding any positioning properties to the to "borders"